# How to add a conjuction to an NSPredicate

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data, nspredicate

How do you use `NSPredicate` for matching multiple conditions?

I have a query `Select * from Entity where name = "Sony" and type ="cd";`
How can I give this `and` in `NSPredicate`?

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793) is from the Apple developer website and has an example of how to use NSPredicate properly

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example if you use an AND or OR condition in NSPredicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"artist  contains[cd] %@ 
OR album  contains[cd] %@ OR title  contains[cd] %@", 
self.searchBar.text, self.searchBar.text, self.searchBar.text];
```